# How Update indivisual Documents in SOLR 4.0 in python?

Tags: python, solr

I want to update a single document from a large solr index of documents?

I tried

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d doc
```

and

```
doc = '[
    {
        "rating": {
            "set": "22"
        },
        "shipDays": {
            "set": "-"
        },
        "name": {
            "set": "Xolo Prime"
        },
        "discount": {
            "set": "9"
        },
        "url": {
            "set": "http://www.abcd.com/product/xolo-prime/683763827810"
        },
        "image": {
            "set": "http://n4.abcd.com/imgs/a/x/2/1-45a05.jpg|http://n4.abcd.com/imgs/a/x/2/2-a98cc.jpg|http://n2.abcd.com/imgs/a/x/2/3-87d1a.jpg|http://n2.abcd.com/imgs/a/x/2/4-7ddb1.jpg|http://n4.abcd.com/imgs/a/x/2/5-609dd.jpg|http://n3.abcd.com/imgs/a/x/2/6-4b7db.jpg"
        },
        "brand": {
            "set": "xolo"
        },
        "pxMrp": {
            "set": "5699"
        },
        "cat": {
            "set": "mobile phones|mobile phones"
        },
        "price": {
            "set": 5231
        },
        "cat1": {
            "set": "mobile phones"
        },
        "cat2": {
            "set": "mobile phones"
        },
        "cat3": {
            "set": ""
        },
        "mergedPdt": {
            "set": 615071
        },
        "seller_cat": {
            "set": "mobiles and tablets|mobile phones"
        },
        "seller": {
            "set": "snapdeal"
        },
        "id": "125865392",
        "stock": {
            "set": "1"
        }
    }
]'
```

Its not Working.

Any other way to Update individual documents in solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this curl command:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/<corename>/update?commit=true -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '<data>'
```

Please replace the `corename` and `data` parameter appropriately.